# Trackpad and Magic Mouse not working properly after Sierra 10.12.4 update

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update, trackpad, mouse

I’ve updated the OS to Sierra 10.12.4 on my Macbook Pro Retina after which Magic Mouse started going crazy with the scrolling speed significantly increased (even with the minimum scrolling speed set in mouse settings), while both the mouse and the trackpad won’t scroll.

Luckily, I was able to revert back to 10.12.3 via Time Machine and everything seems to be working on this version…

What should I do to solve this problem and why does it happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem still persists on Sierra 10.2.5. The funny thing is that it actually *worked* after the update until I shut the Macbook down for the first time. After turning it on, the problem reappeared.

Comment: After this, I reinstalled the Sierra 10.2.5. from the utility menu after boot and the problem dissappeared. But alas – if I leave the Macbook in sleep for a longer period of time the problem gets back, and then I need to reinstall it all over again!